# Divide byte string and return as a byte string

Tags: python

> Write a function called div2bstr that takes a byte string (bstr) and returns a byte string. Each character in the byte string is divided by 2 (integer division) and assembled into a new byte string. Return the new byte string using a string and for loop.

I have tried to implement this with an empty string then concatenating it with a for loop but I am unable to get the correct answer.

```
def div2bstr(bstr):
    final_str = ''
    final_str += [i//2 for i in bstr]
    return final_str
```

When calling `div2bstr(b'Hello')`, the expected result is `b'$2667'`.

I receive errors when I run mine:

```
final_str += [i//2 for i in bstr]

TypeError: can't concat bytes to list
```

I understand that when I am `i` is an integer and that’s why it is unable to concatenate, but I don’t know how to fix this issue and get the proper result.

Comment: Though DYZ has given a great answer already, I believe there are something you need to pay attention in your code: 1) `final_str=''` it is a str instead of byte string  2) `final_str += [i//2 for i in bstr]` left side is a `str` while right side is an int list, which is obviously incorrect  3) I believe you have something else happening in code as the `TypeError` seems not reflecting your mistakes.

Comment: 4) There is no for-loop.  `[i//2 for i in bstr]` is what we call list comprehension, it is not a for loop (although you can write a equivalent for-loop based on that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the list of bytes into a `bytes` object, and you can write the whole function body in one line.

```
def div2bstr(bstr):
    return bytes(i//2 for i in bstr)
```